# Array to string conversion [CORE\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php, line 2094]

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a review & rating page. After viewing the product customer can give review and rating.
My controller/review.ctp code is like this:

```
 public function review($prod_id = NULL)
{
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Product->updateAll(array(
            'Product.rating' => "'".$this->request->data['Product']['rating']."'",
            'Product.review' => "'".$this->request->data['Product']['review']."'",
            array('conditions'=>array(
                'prod_id' => $prod_id))
        ));
        $this->Session->setFlash("Thanks for your feedback !!!");
    }
}
```

But on executing above code i am getting:

```
Notice (8): Array to string conversion    [CORE\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php, line 2094]

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

SQL Query: UPDATE `cakephp`.`products` AS `Product` SET `Product`.`rating` = '4', `Product`.`review` = 'abcd', `Product`.`id` = Array WHERE 1 = 1
```

I am not getting what is the problem. 
Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Query must be `$this->Product->updateAll(array('Product.rating' => "'".$this->request->data['Product']['rating']."'",'Product.review' => "'".$this->request->data['Product']['review']."'"),array('conditions'=>array('Product.id' => $prod_id)));`

Comment: Both of you should have a quick look at the docs: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions** And please, I can't stress that enough, do not manually add quotes around user input, use the database drivers value quoting mechanism instead! @anantkumarsingh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you are hitting is not correct,try this:-

```
$this->Product->updateAll(array('Product.rating' => "'".$this->request->data['Product']['rating']."'",'Product.review' => "'".$this->request->data['Product']['review']."'"),array('conditions'=>array('Pr‌​oduct.id' => $prod_id)));
```

Note:- `)`of first array is misplaced. it must be closed before `condition` array.

in `condition` array it will be `Product.id` not `prod_id`.

Comment: `updateAll` does not escape data automatically. Be sure to escape yourself otherwise you are opening yourself up to sql injection.